# A problem with using packages – wrapfig and hyperref

Tags: errors, hyperref, compiling, wrapfig

I am writing a book using Overleaf. A chapter was written in a separate document and using slightly different setup. When I try inserting the chapter into the book-document I get hundreds of errors, most of them seemingly unconnected to the packages, and the file is unable to compile.

The packages I'm trying to add are the wrapfig package to inserted boxes-of-text in the main text and hyperref to refrence urls in a nicer way.

My current setup is described below. This project has been going on for a while and thus many packages have been added over time.

I would like to 1. understand which packages are clashing and why and 2. to get help correcting the problem.

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}

\frenchspacing

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\usepackage[rightmargin=0pt, noorphans, vskip=\smallskipamount]{quoting}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf}]{caption}

\usepackage{needspace}


\numberwithin{equation}{section}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\renewcommand\footnotemargin{1.2em}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: there is no particular reason for hyperref or wrapfig to clash but what can we do with the code posted, it can not be run to see the error and you do not say what error you got so it is really hard to help. Please edit the question to have a complete small document that produces the eror that you are asking about

Comment: I added the `\documentclass` so your list of packages could be run as a test document but it generates no error???

Comment: If you get errors with either one, you should consider them separate questions.